# DDD: How to handle multiple possible aggregate root links

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm working on a help desk application using DDD. My question is how best to handle an entity that could reference two possible ARs.

I have a `RequestSubscriber` that is a person who subscribes to request updates.

This subscriber is either an `Agent` or `Contact`.

The question is—should I have a optional reference to agent or contact and only fill one or have a generic person reference with an associated type to make sure the link gets to the right place?

Model Options:

```
// This
public class RequestSubscriber : DomainEntity, IPerson
{
    // Constuctors...

    public Guid? Agent_Id { get; private set; }
    public Guid? Contact_Id { get; private set; }
    public SubscriberType Type { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
    public PersonName Name { get; private set; }
}

// Or This
public class RequestSubscriber : DomainEntity, IPerson
{
    // Constuctors...

    public Guid Person_Id { get; private set; }
    public SubscriberType Type { get; private set; }
    public Email Email { get; private set; }
    public PersonName Name { get; private set; }
}
```

Contructors:

```
    // This
    public RequestSubscriber(Guid id, Request request, IPerson person) : base(id)
    {
        Guard.ForNull(request, nameof(request));
        Guard.ForNull(person, nameof(person));

        if(person is Agent agent)
        {
            Email = agent.Email;
            Name = agent.Name;
            Type = SubscriberType.Agent;
        }
        else if (person is Contact contact)
        {
            Email = contact.Email;
            Name = contact.Name;
            Type = SubscriberType.Contact;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Subscribers must be an agent or contact", nameof(person));
        }

        request.Subscribe(this);
    }

    // Or This
    public RequestSubscriber(Guid id, Request request, Agent agent) : base(id)
    {
        Guard.ForNull(request, nameof(request));
        Guard.ForNull(agent, nameof(agent));

        Email = agent.Email;
        Name = agent.Name;
        Type = SubscriberType.Agent;

        request.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public RequestSubscriber(Guid id, Request request, Contact contact) : base(id)
    {
        Guard.ForNull(request, nameof(request));
        Guard.ForNull(contact, nameof(contact));

        Email = contact.Email;
        Name = contact.Name;
        Type = SubscriberType.Contact;

        request.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

Comment: An additional thought is maybe I should really have two different subscribers—agent subscriber and contact subscriber.

Comment: I miss the `Subscriber` class you mentioned. Why and how does it matter to the `RequestSubscriber` what kind the `IPerson` is? What is the invariant/consistency boundary protected by that AR?

Comment: My apologies, the `RequestSubscriber` is the subscriber class name. It matters mostly because email notifications for a `Contact` will differ from `Agent`.

Comment: In this case I would use the second approach (type flag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option may be to add another level of indirection :)

Your `RequestSubscriber` seems to bring together a `Request` and a `Subscriber`.  You are passing in a `Request` but there may be a concept missing in the `Subscriber` part.

In the same was that a `Request` abstracts whatever the request is your `Subscriber` could abstract whatever your subscriber represents.

If there is another reason why you need the `SubscriberType` then perhaps it may change the implementation though.

Comment: I thought about that and IMO that would just proxy the problem from `RequestSubscriber` to `Subscriber`.

Comment: Ah, I re-read your comment and you did mention this.  It is going to depend on what the actual problem is that one is going to be moving.